# Tooltip not showing for nested control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip, devexpress

I have the following piece of code that works great in all but one instance.

```
private void tbxLastName_EditValueChanging(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ChangingEventArgs e)
{
    GetRemainingChars(sender);
}

public void GetRemainingChars(object sender)
{
    var control = sender as TextEdit;
    var maxChars = control.Properties.MaxLength;
    tipCharacterCounter.Show(control.Text.Length + "/" + maxChars, this, control.Location.X, control.Location.Y - control.Height);
}
```

I just repeat this process from any `textbox`.  Unfortunately, I have one control that is more complicated and I cannot get this to work.  The `Event` portion looks like this -->

```
private void memDirectionsToAddress_Popup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MemoExPopupForm popupForm = (sender as DevExpress.Utils.Win.IPopupControl).PopupWindow as MemoExPopupForm;
    MemoEdit meDirections = popupForm.Controls[2] as MemoEdit;
    meDirections.EditValueChanging += new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ChangingEventHandler(meDirections_EditValueChanging);
}

void meDirections_EditValueChanging(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ChangingEventArgs e)
{
    GetRemainingChars(sender);
}
```

What I don't understand is if I replace the `tipCharacterCounter` portion with, say updating a label, it works fine.  It's like the ToolTip is hidden or something but I have tried feeding `Show()` different points to no avail.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of DXPerience are you using?  I've tried the following code using DXperience 10.1.5 and it works fine here:

```
private void memoExEdit1_Popup(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MemoExPopupForm popupForm = (sender as DevExpress.Utils.Win.IPopupControl).PopupWindow as MemoExPopupForm;
    MemoEdit meDirections = popupForm.Controls[2] as MemoEdit;
    meDirections.EditValueChanging += new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ChangingEventHandler(meDirections_EditValueChanging);
}

void meDirections_EditValueChanging(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ChangingEventArgs e) {
    GetRemainingChars(sender);
}

public void GetRemainingChars(object sender) {
    TextEdit control = sender as TextEdit;
    int maxChars = control.Properties.MaxLength;
    tipCharacterCounter.ShowHint(control.Text.Length + "/" + maxChars, control, ToolTipLocation.RightBottom);
}
```

Comment: 10.1.4  I was using Windows ToolTip instead of DevEx's.  Not sure why but it works fine with DevEx's.  Thanks.